# Как создать такой массив из mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Подскажите как создать такой массив из mysql на php?

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [id_city] => 1
            [name_city] => Ачинск
            [dealers] => Array
                (
                    [name_dil] => Дилер 1
                    [phone_dil] => телефон
                    [email_dil] => емейл
                    [site_dil] => сайт
                )
                (
                    [name_dil] => Дилер 2
                    [phone_dil] => телефон
                    [email_dil] => емейл
                    [site_dil] => сайт
                )
                (
                    [name_dil] => Дилер 3
                    [phone_dil] => телефон
                    [email_dil] => емейл
                    [site_dil] => сайт
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [id_city] => 2
            [name_city] => Барнаул
            [dealers] => Array
                (
                    [name_dil] => Дилер 1
                    [phone_dil] => телефон
                    [email_dil] => емейл
                    [site_dil] => сайт
                )
                (
                    [name_dil] => Дилер 2
                    [phone_dil] => телефон
                    [email_dil] => емейл
                    [site_dil] => сайт
                )

        )

)
```

Непонятно, как это накодить на php. Я пытался сделать такой код. Но он выводит только 1 дилера почему-то.

```
$sql = 'SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `dilery` WHERE dilery.city_dil = city.id_city AND dilery.`status` != 1) as `count`, city.name_city, city.id_city
        FROM dilery
        INNER JOIN city ON dilery.city_dil = city.id_city
        WHERE city.region != "1" AND dilery.`status` != 1
        GROUP BY name_city
        ORDER BY name_city';

$row_dealers = mysqli_query($link,$sql); 
$dealersDetails = array(); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($row_dealers) > 0) {
    $dealersCount = 0;
    while ($city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_dealers)) {
        $idCity = $city['id_city'];
        $name = $city['name_city'];
        $dealersDetails[$dealersCount] = $city;
        $sql = 'SELECT dilery.name_dil, dilery.phone_dil, dilery.email_dil, dilery.site_dil
        FROM dilery
        INNER JOIN city ON dilery.city_dil = city.id_city
        WHERE dilery.city_dil = '.$idCity.' AND dilery.`status` != 1
        ORDER BY name_city';
        $row_dealers_item = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($row_dealers_item) > 0) {
            while ($dealers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_dealers_item)) {
                $dealersDetails[$dealersCount]['dealers'] = $dealers;
                $dealersDetails[$dealersCount]['name_city'] = $name;
            }
        } else {
            $dealersDetails[$dealersCount]['dealers'] = [];
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($dealersDetails);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Удалось сформировать json файл с такой структурой

```
Array
(
    [Dealers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_city] => 46
                    [name_city] => Абакан
                    [dealers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 155
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 1
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_city] => 1
                    [name_city] => Ачинск
                    [dealers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 1
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 1
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id_city] => 2
                    [name_city] => Барнаул
                    [dealers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 2
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 1
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 4
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 2
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 5
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 3
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 7
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 4
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 142
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 5
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id_city] => 3
                    [name_city] => Благовещенск
                    [dealers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dealer_id] => 8
                                    [dealer_name] => Дилер 1
                                    [dealer_phone] => телефон
                                    [dealer_email] => емейл
                                    [dealer_site] => сайт
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто вкладывайте массив в массив

```
 $arr = [
            0 => [
              'id_city' => 1,
              'name_city' => 'Ачинск',
              'dealers' => [
                 0 => [
                    'name_dil' => 'Дилер 1',
                    'phone_dil' => 'телефон',
                    'email_dil' => 'емейл',
                    'site_dil' => 'сайт',
                 ], 
                 1 => [
                    'name_dil' => 'Дилер 2',
                    'phone_dil' => 'телефон',
                    'email_dil' => 'емейл',
                    'site_dil' => 'сайт',
                 ]
             ]
          ]
```

Comment: а по коду не подскажете? я дополнил свой вопрос с примером, что мне удалось накодить. Но это работает не совсем корректно

Comment: @arsi87 получается что вам надо json сформировать ? так ?

Comment: @MaximLensky вообще я не думал про json. Я думал вывести в массив данные из 2х таблиц. А потом распарсить их в аккордеон,чтобы не было кучи запросов, как у меня сейчас. Сейчас я формирую аккордеон так. 2 запроса. 1 из них в идет в цикле. Поэтому очень много запросов получается и страница долго грузиться

Comment: @arsi87 ну если сформировать json на php а вывести данные после этого на ajax то будет реакция мгновенная ...то есть работать будет быстро

Comment: @MaximLensky проблема только в том, что я не знаю javascript( это будет для меня большей проблемой, чем вывод на php

Comment: @arsi87 сформируйте php json только корректный (что бы было ясно что и куда )- потом сюда напишите

Comment: @MaximLensky удалось сформировать json